# Definition of Boolean with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

With Xcode 6 I get the following two warnings:

```
.../objects/DOArticle.h:26:42: 'getter' attribute on property 'updated' does not match the property inherited from 'NSManagedObject'
.../objects/DOArticle.h:26:42: Property type 'NSNumber *' is incompatible with type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') inherited from 'NSManagedObject'
```

The Object is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * commonId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * read;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * updated;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * removed;
```

And the type in the data model is set to Boolean.
I don't know exactly why I get them now, and what I should do about it.

Comment: Did you have Xcode create the subclass for you or are you hand coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `NSManagedObject` already has a property named "updated"

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isUpdated, readonly) BOOL updated
```

Since you're inheriting from `NSManagedObject` and have a property of the same name, this creates a conflict. Even though in your core data model you set the type of your own "updated" property to Boolean, as you can see, CoreData stores it as an NSNumber. So basically you're changing the type of a property you inherit which causes the compiler to complain.

The best thing to do is to pick a different name for your property.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is something new in the new SDK, and that is why I didn't encounter it before. I will have a look and see how easy changing the name is.

Comment: This has always been the case. In the iOS 8 SDK the accessor method "isUpdated" was redefined as a readonly property. `-isUpdated` has always returned BOOL, and should not be overridden.